# What's the difference between "Foo".equals(maybeFoo) and maybeFoo==null?false:maybeFoo.equals("Foo")?

Tags: java, equals, strong-typing

I'm facing a question to write a piece of java code like:

```
boolean isFoo(String maybeFoo){
    //Return true if maybeFoo is equal to "Foo"
    //Don't throw any exceptions.
}
```

I have two choices:

```
1. return "Foo".equals(maybeFoo);
2. return maybeFoo==null?false:maybeFoo.equals("Foo");
```

I choose the number 1, but I cannot give a reason why number 2 is wrong. I said to the interviewer, it's just my habit to deal with a strong type language. But he seems not satisfied.

Comment: What is the method `maybeFoo` in 2.?

Comment: Your second option could also be `return maybeFoo!=null && maybeFoo.equals("Foo");`.

Comment: I think the options were given by the interviewer

Comment: What about [`return Objects.equals(maybeFoo, "Foo")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))? This is another way, and also a clean one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between those is exactly what you wrote in the 2 options

```
"Foo".equals(maybeFoo);
```

Is a most common implemented check because you don't have to take care about a null check... (even because is only one check more)

On the other hand this

```
maybeFoo.equals("Foo")
```

Will throw a NPE exception just because are calling methods on a  null referenced object

Comment: but no.2 checks the null at first.

Comment: yes, I see, but the less things you check the better is the performance.

Answer (score 2):

First it should be said that both versions provide the same output and none of them throw an exception, so it's just a matter of which one is a **cleaner** way of writing it.

```
return "Foo".equals(maybeFoo);
```

is a better way of doing what is specified because even if `maybeFoo` is null, the java function `equals` returns `false` and doesn't throw an exception.

However, if `maybeFoo` was null, you couldn't call the function `equals` on it, otherwise you would get a `NullPointerException`. Hence, you have to check for it in the second example.

The point is that if you can make something work with **less** and **cleaner** code, you should go with that, because that makes your code more readable and less prone to errors.

Comment: *"is a better way"* That's just an opinion ;P. *"However, if `maybeFoo` was false"* This is never possible. *"cleaner code"* Calling yoda conditions "cleaner" also also an opinion (imo a bad one)

Comment: Meant to say null oviously, not false. Fixed that. I don't see how removing the need for an additional null check by using a property of an already defined java function and therefore shortening your code is not a "cleaner" way of writing code.

Comment: Depends on your relation do `null` and if `null` is a valid value there. There is the opinion that `null` should not be used as a valid value, since it mostly mean a programming error. This will stay hidden when you silently fail your test and you don't know why, because you think that `maybeFoo` _should_ contain `"Foo"` ([more about avoiding `null`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained)).

Comment: I can't really follow you there. Both options presented to him by the interviewer produce exactly the same output. If you input `null` as an argument - whether by mistake or because it might be a valid value - the function returns `false`. They both don't throw an exception or anything else to show that there might have been a programming mistake. So this is the way the question was specified by the interviewer. What you say generally holds true (which is why you should usually check the input to your function to see if it's actually valid or not), however, that is not required here.

Comment: Well yes, I'm meant it more generally, not matched on this question here.